# Error adding a column to an Access database using SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am trying to do a very simple thing: add a new column to an existing query or table use an SQL query. However, every time I attempt this I get the "Query must have at least one destination field" error. I'm not sure where my error lies.

The code I have tried is:

```
ALTER TABLE Notes_file
ADD DateOfBirth date;
```

I've pulled this off of documentation for the ALTER TABLE command. I've tried with both queries and tables, and with different column types.

While I have your attention, I ultimately want to put this into my VB Studio code. Once I get the ALTER command to work properly, not sure how I should implement this in VB Studio. Do I use .CreateQueryDef or .Execute?

```
Dim alterQuery As String = "ALTER TABLE FormStats ADD freq_tot single;"

With qdfTemp1
    rstTemp = .OpenRecordset(DAO.RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenSnapshot)
    Debug.Print("beginning read of initial query(1)")

    With rstTemp
        Dim listing_form As String = VB6.Format(rstTemp.form_code.value, "##")
        .Execute("FormStats", alterQuery)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the VB.NET code too. I would expect to use `.ExecuteNonQuery`, but you might be doing things via a different route.

Comment: Sounds like you might be trying to use an UPDATE-type query, within Access, to run that ALTER statement.  An UPDATE query will expect there to be destination fields that are going to be updated.  Check the type of query that you are running

Comment: Why are you trying to write code like it's VB6 in the first place? You're almost three decades too late. How about writing proper VB.NET code, using ADO.NET? You could then call `ExecuteNonQuery` to execute SQL code that doesn't generate a result set.